# How to use jQuery filter function with event delegation?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to bind the change of all the textboxes(having class `.box`) under Box2 column who have the blue button(having class `.blue` which is dynamic in some cases) in their row.

Below is the screenshot of the HTML I have which is just a HTML table which has 3 columns(Box1,Box2 & for the button):

[image]

Class `.blue` could be present on some buttons on the page load & also could be removed/added to the buttons as result of another Ajax operation.

jQuery `.on()` has 
`.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )` 
is it possible to use `.filter()` in the selector part where I can use a function like

```
jQuery('.box').filter(function(){
       return jQuery(this).closest('tr').find('.blue').length
    });
```

to filter out the needed textboxes & then bind there change event?

Considering the `#parent` is the parent div of the HTML I was trying

`jQuery('#parent').on('change','.box',..);` but this will listen to the change of all the box2 elements whereas I want it to listen to the specific ones only.

Ideas please?

Thanks.

Comment: We can not really copy from `screen-shots`.. Do share a demo/fiddle...

Comment: @Rayon did you not understood the question?

Comment: We can try to understand your issue but its hard to provide any solutions without seeing code

Comment: I am sorry but this is somewhat a conceptual thing & I do not have the code for this

Comment: @techie_28, How about grabbing `e.target` element in `click-handler` or applying `if` condition in handler based on `$(this)` ?

Comment: Without knowing DOM how can we suggest anything?

Comment: I want to write the event listener for the textboxes under Box2 column which have a corresponding blue button in their HTML row.

Comment: @RRR added the filter function code & HTML info there.. HTML is nothing but a table with 3 columns as shown in the screenshot.

Comment: @techie_28, You are not ok with the if condition ?

Comment: @Rayon I want to write the listener that responds the specific text boxes only.If condition would be helpful when it is listening to all of them

Comment: Since you have not shared any HTML code I have assumed few things and created a demo kindly check https://jsfiddle.net/npxedv04/  is this what you want?

Comment: @RRR HTML is pretty much correct but this is not what I m looking to do

Comment: @techie_28, In event delegation, we are binding events on the parent event and listening events on it based on the `target`.. The only thing we are certain about is the `specific-selector` of the `target-element`.. Well in the cases link `specific-child` or `specific-sibling`, doing things in the handler is the only way!

Comment: @Rayon so there is not a way to define a handler like I was thinking?

Comment: @Rayon I may have about 100 or more boxes under .box2 that is why I wanted some specificity with the handler.

Comment: @techie_28, As far as my opinion is concerned, I doubt it is possible.. Lets   wait for other answers...

Comment: @Rayon but do you think `$('.parent').on('change','.box2 input',function(){..`  listens on parent changes or the `.box2` changes?

Comment: @Rayon I think you may be right here.. from the manual:
"An event-delegation approach attaches an event handler to only one element, the tbody, and the event only needs to bubble up one level "

Comment: @Rayon its is there https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/.. in the intro it states the answer. Please post an answer & I will accept it.

Comment: @techie_28, Have posted an answer... Not sure how much it will be beneficial for other users...

Comment: @Rayon from the manual here http://api.jquery.com/on/
`$( "#dataTable tbody tr" ).on( "click", function() {` & `$( "#dataTable tbody" ).on( "click", "tr", function() {` event delegation approach is better because it attaches to one element only & first one will attach 100 rows if there are.Please post answer accordingly as your comment was close to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In event delegation, we are binding events on the parent element and listening events on it based on the target(`selector`). The only thing we are certain about is the `specific-selector` of the target-element. Well, in the cases link `specific-child` or `specific-sibling` of the dynamically appended element, doing things in the handler(callback) is the only way!

***Delegated events*** have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers.

**Note:** Attaching many delegated event handlers near the top of the document tree can degrade performance. Each time the event occurs, jQuery must compare all selectors of all attached events of that type to every element in the path from the event target up to the top of the document. For best performance, attach delegated events at a document location as close as possible to the target elements. Avoid excessive use of document or document.body for delegated events on large documents. [[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/on/)]

Comment: Yes I realized that binding on `#parent` & listening to change of all the `.box` classes would be the same as would be the listening to change of specific `.box` classes. Considering this @Gerard & @madalinivascu's answers were also correct.. thanks for your time.. :)

Comment: Yes.. This 4 hours were like 40.. So many comments :) Pleasure :)

Answer (score 1):

use a if to test if the button(.box) has a blue class

```
$('.parent').on('change','.box2 input',function(){
    if($(this).closest('tr').find('.box').is('.blue')) {
      //do code here
   }
});
```

Comment: I want to trap the `change` of the textbox not the click of the button.

Comment: if you provide the html i will be able to do a precise selection

Comment: @Rayon what elements are dynamic?

Comment: HTML is nothing but a table with 3 columns as shown in the screenshot

Comment: @techie_28 can't you just drop the html in the question?

Comment: @madalinivascu I could but that wont help.. The question is pretty elaborated.. I need to write a listener which traps the change of the textboxes which have a corresponding blue class on button in their row.The blue class could be removed/added dynamically depending on an ajax result.

Comment: if only the class of the button is dynamical the the above code should work

Comment: @madalinivascu `$('.parent').on('change','.box2 input'...` this line is still listening to all the boxes I believe. The filtration is occurring in `if($(this).closest('tr').find('.box').is('.blue'))`

Comment: yes,if you want to be more specific you can target only one input with the corespunding button

Comment: @madalinivascu can we not use jQuery  `.filter()` function in place of `.box2 input` to point to the required boxes?By specific boxes I mean ones meeting the criteria.

Comment: why do a loop when you don't need to?

Comment: @madalinivascu, Can you apply `.filter` over `elements` which are not there in DOM.. This is a example of `Event Delegation`

Comment: yes for exemple : `var x = '<span></span><span class="red"></span>';$(x).filter(function(el){return $(el).attr('class') == 'red'});`

Comment: @madalinivascu, Will `.filter` select elements which are not there in `DOM`.. And first of all, it expects `selector` as second argument...not `jQuery-wrapped` object..

Comment: @Rayon what second argument?

Comment: @madalinivascu, [`.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: what he can do is add a class to the input when the ajax is completed and bind a event to that

Comment: there are better and simpler ways to do this, why stick with filter??

Comment: @madalinivascu we know those methods.. just was wondering if possible via  jQuery `.on()`

Comment: directly putting the result of filter in the on function as a param is impossible

Answer (score 1):

Include a separate check for the button. Without any code it's not possible to give you the correct code

```
jQuery('#parent').on('change','.box',..);
  if ($(this).next().hasClass('blue')) {
    // Do other stuff
  }
```

Comment: this again listens on all the boxes.I need to write a listener for the specific boxes only.